# Distributed Query Caching In Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, performance

Can we maintain consistency in query caches across multiple nodes? Or else I should just drop the idea of using query cache in a distributed architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to MySQL's Query cache, then NO.  It is unavailable in Galera cluster and Group replication -- for good reason.  The maintenance of it far outweighs the benefit.

If you are referring to some other caching, I would *probably* advise against it, for much the same reasons.

If you would like to explain what you are doing, we can discuss further.

The *better* alternatives:

- Speed up queries via better indexing, schema design, query formulation, etc.
- Rethink other things that lead to slowdowns.

That is, focus on making the system fast enough not to need a distributed cache.